# How to check if a value is in allowlist?

Tags: python, arrays

```
exampleArray = [2, "a", "b"]
allowedItems = ["a", "b"]
```

How could repeat the number of times in exampleArray[0] until the end of the array that alse checks if that
value is in allowedItems?

I have tried this but it doesnt work:

```
for x in exampleArray[0]:
    if exampleArray[x] in allowedItems:
        print("Valid Item")
```

please send example code

Comment: I think you need to read about [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) and [iterators](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#iterators) in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for x in exampleArray:
    if x in allowedItems:
        print(f"{x} is a valid Item")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to achieve this.

```
example_array = [2, "a", "b"]
allowed_items = ["a", "b"]
for _ in range(example_array[0]):
    for item in example_array[1:]:
        if item in allowed_items:
            print(f"{item} is in allowed items")
```

The loop will be iterated `examle_array[0]` number of times like in the case above 2 times and then for each item, except the first one (`example_array[0]` - 2 ), check if the item is in `allowed_list`.

Below is the output:

```
a is in allowed list
b is in allowed list
a is in allowed list
b is in allowed list
```

Answer (score 0):

```
exampleArray = [2, "a", "b"]
allowedItems = ["a", "b"]
for x in exampleArray:
    if x in allowedItems:
        print("Valid Item: "+str(x))
    else:
        print("Invalid Item: "+str(x))
```

**Output:-**

```
Invalid Item: 2
Valid Item: a
Valid Item: b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Another way: You can use set()

exampleArray = [2, "a", "b"]
allowedItems = ["a", "b"]

# Just want to know allowed list items
# intersection and '&' is same
set(allowedItems).intersection(set(exampleArray))
set(allowedItems) & set(exampleArray)

# Print allowed items list
[ print(x+' is Allowed') for x in set(allowedItems).intersection(set(exampleArray)) ]
[ print(x+' is Allowed') for x in set(allowedItems) & set(exampleArray) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension:

```
exampleArray = [2, "a", "b"]
allowedItems = ["a", "b"]

[print(f"{i} is a valid Item") if i in set(allowedItems) else print(f"{i} is not a valid Item") for i in exampleArray]
```